# setting servlet in web.xml to use in JQuery Ajax call

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I have created a class which extends `HttpServlet` in a package called `controller`

I created this in this src folder and have the build path output folder set to webapp/WEB-INF/classes

In my web.xml I have

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>SearchController</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>controller.SearchController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

I have a JQuery Ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
            url : "SearchController",
            data : "q=test", 
            ...            
});
```

So I expect my servlet class to post something like SearchController?q=test

This doesn't work. Have I specified the wrong servlet-class in web.xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have entry for servlet-mapping as well in your web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>SearchController</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/SearchController</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You can give any value in url-pattern node and you can access the servlet with that value

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet in web.xml should be bound to URL using `<servlet-mapping>`.In your javascript function ajax should use URL, which was bound in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

> There is no difference between an ajax call and normal HTTP call for a
>   servlet. In both the cases server will response in same way and should
>   be mapped in same way.